# Cisco AP, how to show dot11 wpa handshake timeout?

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface, ios

Please help me with a newbie question regarding Cisco AP CLI .

According to this [Cisco doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/12.4.25d.JA/Command/reference/cr12425d-chap2.html#wp3734568) , I know how to change `WPA handshake timeout` value to 2000 milliseconds.

```
Cisco1242AG-1(config)#dot11 wpa handshake timeout 2000
```

But, how do I query its current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command *is* present in the configuration (`show run`) then the timeout is as configured.

If the command *is not* present in the configuration (`show run`) then the timeout is the default 100 milliseconds.

I have yet to find it in any other show output.  My first hunch was it might also be present in `show controllers dot11radio 0`.  Nope.

Comment: Thank you. The ``show run`` command does the trick. Using ``show controllers dot11radio 0`` produces quite many info, but no "wpa handshake timeout".